# Is FAA's Order 8260.58A complementary to the TERPS manual as far as SID design is concerned?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-procedures, departure-sid

I am studying FAA's United States Standard for Terminal Instrument Procedures (TERPS) to learn how a SID is designed and what kind of rules and constraints one has to take into consideration. I am also studying the PBN Instrument Procedure Design manual (Order 8260.58A), which describes the instrument procedure design for Performance Based Navigation procedures.

However, chapter 14 of the TERPS manual, titled "Departure Procedure Construction", makes no mention of the Order 8260.58 (only once at the beginning for RNAV-equipped aircraft criteria) and proceeds to describe the departure procedures construction as if the Obstacle Clearance Areas that calculates apply to all kinds of departure procedures, without any notice that e.g. "For PBN procedures, consult Order 8260.58".

Could someone help me to clarify how to interpret these two manuals correctly, at least as far as the design of departure procedures is concerned? There seem to be so many rules related to this particular subject and I got a bit lost.